A woman reporter investigates gorillas in Africa
I'm looking for a late 70s or 80s movie that a woman reporter investigates gorillas in rain forests at the equatorial africa. She was giving them food, taking pictures of them, writing her observation about them to finish and publish the article to her newspaper / magazine. 
She was white, in her 40s, had black medium hair, medium sized. She was american or british. She was on her own most of her days. She had a small cabin in a village in the deep woods. One day a white man had come to the village. I don't remember his profession but he could be a journalist, I guess. He removed his wedding ring because he had fallen in love with her. He had joined to her trips to investigate gorillas and he had surprised of the behaviours of the gorillas. 
One day when at a heavy rain outside, he had come to her cabin. After a small talk they had made love in a bath tub. After that she said "I know you are married". He said "How do you know that?". She replied "Because you removed your wet coat outside of the cabin, not inside. No women give permission to a wet coat in her house and you did this automatically." 
He had accepted it and respond it a cliche come back. "Yes I'm married, but I had fallen in love with you and I want to spend the rest of my life here with you."
He was white, tall, blonde, had a balding head, in his late 40s or early 50s. I can't remember the rest of the movie. 

If you type "woman gorilla reporter Africa movie" into Google, this is the first movie that comes up.

This is Gorillas in the Mist:

Gorillas in the Mist is a 1988 American drama film directed by Michael
  Apted and starring Sigourney Weaver as naturalist Dian Fossey. It
  tells the true story of her work in Rwanda with mountain gorillas and
  was nominated for five Academy Awards.

Below is a part of the plot matching your description:

National Geographic, which funds her efforts, takes an increasingly
  marked interest in her work and dispatches photographer Bob Campbell
  (Bryan Brown) to highlight her research. Fossey, initially unreceptive
  towards the outsider Campbell, grows increasingly attached to him
  after several photo sessions with the gorillas, and the two eventually
  become lovers, in spite of Campbell's marriage. Campbell proposes to
  divorce his wife and marry her but insists that she would have to
  spend time away from Karisoke and her gorillas, leading her to call
  off the tryst and ending their relationship.


